# French Chrome browser in Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, localization, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run Selenium tests with a French browser. 
Right now i setup my Chrome to be in French but when i run the test it opens up English Chrome. Is there way around this?

Thanks.
I'm using C# to code this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a profile and to use with chrome that defaults lang to French. Otherwise there may be a chrome switch for it (can't remember thou)

Comment: How would you go about this? Im fairly new to Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can try this when you setup your 'french' Google Chrome profile:

1. Type a search query into Google
2. Click the toolbar in the top right corner and select "Search settings"
3. Click on "Location", type in your address, and click Save

But keep in mind that Selenium by default raises 'clean' browser instances. So double-check that your current Chrome is with correct profile settings/desired capabilities.